# How to make the text in the button bold?

Tags: html, css

I can't make the text bold

I tried this, but it does not work:

```css
.auth_subm {
  height: 20pt;
  width: 130pt;
  font: 10pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, bold;
  margin: 2pt;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<input value="how get answers" type="button" class="auth_subm" />
```

Comment: Why are you using a button + JS in the first place? Just use a regular HTML link.

Comment: @Quentin i need so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've placed `bold` in your comma-separated list of font names, so if there isn't a generic `sans-serif` font available it will look for one named `bold`.

See the [documentation for `font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font). **Order** matters.

Put `bold` at the *front* of the list of properties in the shorthand.

```css
.auth_subm {
  height: 20pt;
  width: 130pt;
  font: bold 10pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 2pt;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<input value="how get answers" type="button" onclick="location.href='otv.html'" class="auth_subm" />
```

Comment: still not bold on chrome

Comment: chrome macos not bold as you can see https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUSpX.png

Comment: @dgknca — My screenshot is from Chrome on macOS.

Comment: Also not bold on Chrome/MacOs (Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)) here.. When you force '-webkit-appearance: none;' it seems to work.. Strange..

Comment: Every OS uses renders the inputfields differently. That's why you should use a button type! But i'm going to let go now :p

Comment: @Goombah still not bold with `-webkit-appearance: none;`

Comment: @dgknca Which macOs are you on? Does  -webkit-appearance: button; does anything? (combined with font-weight: bold of course)..

Comment: @Goombah mojave. I deleted `font:` line and tried with `font-weight: bold` but not works.

Comment: @dgknca At this point is honestly better for you to use a button instead of an input, it'll give you better control on its appearance

Comment: @IvanS95 As I said in a comment, it is better for the OP (who is not dgknca) to *use a link* and not any kind of button at all.

Comment: @dgknca — I don't edit code out of the OPs original code when doing so doesn't make an answer significantly clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using font-weight bold on input field, you should change your input field to a button field.
However don't forget to say it's a submit button in type!

## Example

```html
<button type="submit">
    <b>Bold text!</b>
</button>
```

Comment: Yeah because of Mac vs Windows problems. If you want to style the text consistent, don't use an input field but a button field. Changing the code was necessary for the solution.

Answer (score -2):

Add a class with font weight like below

```
.auth_subm {
  height: 20pt;
  width: 130pt;
  font: bold 10pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 2pt;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight:700;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/c8kdhbmy/2/

Comment: You don't use input

Comment: @dgknca I've modified exactly like your input. Can you check now?

Comment: still not bold mate

Comment: @dgknca I've updated. Can you check now? If not tell exactly what do you want as output?